# Passing touch to next responder or other sub-view iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, touch

I am sure that this problem will be easily resolved however I am relatively new to iOS development. I am trying to handle passing touch events to children that are lower in the draw order on a UIView. For example -

I create extended UIImageView to create my MoveableImage class. This class is just basically UIImageView that implements the touchesBegan,touchesEnded and touchesMoved-

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


[self showFrame];

//if multitouch dont move
if([[event allTouches]count] > 1)
{
    return;
}



    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject ];

    // Animate the first touch
    CGPoint colorPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.superview];


    //if color is alpha of 0 , they are touching the frame and bubble to next responder
    UIColor *color = [self colorOfPoint:colorPoint];
    [color getRed:NULL green:NULL blue:NULL alpha:&touchBeganAlpha];
    NSLog(@"alpha : %f",touchBeganAlpha);

    if(touchBeganAlpha > 0)
    {
          [self animateFirstTouchAtPoint:touchPoint];
    }
    else {
        [super.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }



}
```

So the end result is basically this- If they are touching the frame of the imageView and not the image inside the other image that will be underneath can possibly respond. See this image for an example.

[image: Passing touch to lower view]

So far I have tried next responder however that does not solve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Resolved- I stopped checking the alpha on the touchesBegan and touchesMoved. Ovveriding pointInside allowed the UIView to handle that for me.

```
-(BOOL) pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
  BOOL superResult = [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
  if(!superResult)
  {
   return superResult;
  }

  if(CGPointEqualToPoint(point, self.previousTouchPoint))
  {
     return self.previousTouchHitTestResponse;
  }else{
     self.previousTouchPoint = point;
  }

  BOOL response = NO;

  //if image is nil then return yes and fall back to super
  if(self.image == nil)
   {
     response = YES;
   }

  response = [self isAlphaVisibleAtPoint:point];
  self.previousTouchHitTestResponse = response;
  return response;





}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override instead `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method for your subclass of UIImageView. (It is a method of uiview that each subclass can override)

The UIView uses this method in `hitTest:withEvent:` to determine which subview should receive a touch event. If pointInside:withEvent: returns YES, then the subview’s hierarchy is traversed; otherwise, its branch of the view hierarchy is ignored.

Check the source code on github of [OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton). They handle tap event only for the opaque part of a button.